# Trim end of string if it contains certein text

Tags: sql, oracle

So if field contains text in bold

"2011-11-11 11:11; Some text; **Kod nr 1:** 999999"

I need result like

"2011-11-11 11:11; Some text; "

or

"2011-11-11 11:11; Some text; Kod nr 1: ******"

If field doesn't contain "Kod nr 1:" nothing should happen with string.

I need to do this in SELECT statement

Comment: `field = CASE WHEN field LIKE ''%"Kord nr 1"%' THEN REPLACE( field, '2011-11-11', '' ) ELSE field END`

Comment: Please post some sample data and needed result to better explain your need

Comment: Edited my main post

Comment: you can use regexp_replace

Comment: Ugh, another comma seperated column anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT field 
  FROM thetable WHERE condition
```

Result:

```
2011-11-11 11:11; Some text; Kod nr 1: 999999"
```

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN field LIKE '%Kod nr 1%' 
            THEN SUBSTR(field, 0, INSTR(field, 'Kod nr 1:') - 1)
            ELSE field 
       END 
  FROM thetable WHERE condition
```

Result:

```
2011-11-11 11:11; Some text;
```

Here is another:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(field, 'Kod nr 1:.*', '') 
  FROM thetable WHERE condition
```

Result:

```
2011-11-11 11:11; Some text;
```

Comment: Thank you :) REGEXP_REPLACE was the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

This replace the "9999" with *

```
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '(Kod nr 1: )(.*)', '\1 ****')             
    FROM table
```

Comment: yup, you are right, it is not necessary. I update the answer